# Chart.js zeros handling

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, chart.js

I'm working with chart.js and to render a doughnut chart. I want to set the initial chart total value to zero so it can render a full " empty" chart. When I instatiate the chart with zeros it does not render. I cannot find how it handle zeros in the developer documentation.

```
var kPoints = 000;
var mPoints = 000;
var tPoints = 000;
var cPoints = 000;
var doughnutData = [ {
    value : kPoints,
    color : "#FF8000"
}, {
    value : mPoints,
    color : "#99CC00"
}, {
    value : tPoints,
    color : "#0099CC"
}, {
    value : cPoints,
    color : "#333333"
}, ];
var ctx = $("#profileChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading the source code for `Chart.js` I've found that the it tries to sum each of the `value` fields in its datasource before rendering the chart (see the use of `segmentTotal` [here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L740)).

To workaround this, use `null` for all the values and set one (or more) of the data points to a very small, *near* zero value. I've used a float notation here for one of the values:

```
var kPoints = null;
var mPoints = null;
var tPoints = null;
var cPoints = 1e-10;
```

After that, the example below re-renders the chart (after a 3 second delay) with different data values to show a case of the values updating from the default "dark" chart to a filled out version:

```
setTimeout(function () {

    // Generate a new, random value for each of the data points
    doughnutData.forEach(function (item) {
        item.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    });

    var ctx = $("#profileChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData);
}, 3000);
```

**JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterXen/6S9DB/3/**

Comment: I did that exactly. The only difference is that I  used cPoints = 0.00000001(instead of your notation) wich turns unperceptive in the chart! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a running total of the values when building the doughnut data.
If there are zero data points, or the total value of all data points is zero, then simply inject an extra dummy point with a label like "No Data" along with an either imperceptible (near-zero) value or a dummy value like 1.  In either case, you'll end up with a valid chart with a single category like "No Data".